# Why does Android let me write into a folder but not its parent?

Tags: android

I have created a folder at /storage/emulated/0/Download/my_app_name.
I can write to the file /storage/emulated/0/Download/my_app_name/backup/my_app_backup.zip, but not to the file /storage/emulated/0/Download/my_app_name/logs.txt, and I have no idea of why one would work but the other wouldn't.

I'm on API 33.

Comment: Indeed. That makes no sense as long as they are both files of your app and not already existing ones created by another app. Or by your app and you did uninstall your app after that. Are there other things you did not tell?